# Ruby on Rails - Bullet/N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rails-bullet

On Rails 4. I recently installed the bullet gem for my development environment to clear up my app's N+1 queries. Relevant models:

**Submissions**: Belongs to Categories and Users. Has many SubmissionDetails.

**Users:** Has many Submissions

**Categories:** Has many Submissions. Belongs to Awards.

**Awards:** Has many Categories (and Submissions through Categories)

**SubmissionDetails:** Belongs to Submissions

In my submission's index page, I have an `each do` statement to display each submission made by the current user.

```
<% current_user.submissions.order('created_at DESC').in_groups_of(3, false) do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% group.each do |submission| %>
```

After that, I list information about the submission, including its associated category, award, and submission details information. Bullet is saying I'm having N+1 issues with this statement:

```
N+1 Query detected Submission => [:category] Add to your finder: :include => [:category]
N+1 Query detected Submission => [:user] Add to your finder: :include => [:user]
N+1 Query detected Submission => [:submission_details] Add to your finder: :include => [:submission_details]
```

Every time I try to add `.includes` with all three of those models, it only picks the first one I list (this is not surprising). I figure I need to go a different route when multiple models are involved--perhaps a join statement?

(When I make :category the first item, it adds this notice):

```
N+1 Query detected Category => [:award] Add to your finder: :include => [:award]
```

(So I also need to include as part of the statement a way to make Award fit in there as well, which, again, has many Submissions through Categories).

So assuming I can't do one `.includes` for three different models, is there another way to go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to be more clear, let me make the details more visible:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions
end

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :submission_details
end

class SubmissionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :award
  has_many   :submissions
end

class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :submissions, through: :categories
end
```

If I understand correctly, for your current_user, you are listing his submissions.
For each submission you want to list submission_details and the category it belongs.
For every category you list the award too.

```
<% current_user.submissions.order('created_at DESC').in_groups_of(3, false) do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% group.each do |submission| %>
      ...
      <div><%= submission.category %></div>
      <div><%= submission.category.award %></div>
      <%= submission.submissions_details.each do |submission_detail| %>
        ...
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can remove N+1 problem by using `includes` in the following manner:

```
current_user.submissions.includes(:submission_details, :category => :award)
```

For more details about `includes` please refer to:

1. [Rails guides eager-loading-associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)
2. [Rails guides eager-loading-multiple-associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)
3. [Rails api - includes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes)

associations

Comment: Thanks so much for that excellent formatting, that looks a lot better than what I laid out! For the record, I have discovered what my problem has been--it is a possible bug with bullet! See this URL: https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet/issues/147

Answer (score 2):

To include those associations, I would create a scope for submissions. While you're at it, add a `latest` scope.

```
class Submission
  scope :eager,  -> { includes(:submission_details, :category => [:award]) }
  scope :latest, -> { order("created_at DESC") }
end
```

Then simply

`current_user.submissions.latest.eager [...]`

You shouldn't have to include `:user`, but I've noticed Rails isn't too clever about such references.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just found out what my problem is for this issue I've been working on! See this URL: https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet/issues/147 Everything I tried I kept getting that "unused" message. So I'm not going insane!!

Comment: Great to hear @Rachel9494!